# Java JPanel used as Canvas to draw text from keyboard input

Tags: java, keyboard, jpanel

I'm trying to make a Java11 GUI with Swing and I'm using a `JPanel` as a Canvas to draw on it images/drawing and I do also want to introduce some text on the Panel so that I can export the whole content of `JPanel` later.

Thought about using `drawString()` method in my `PaintComponent()` method, so should I use a `JOptionPane` to insert keyboard input or there are other better practices to write directly on `JPanel` until Enter key press or Escape.

Also, the main question I have regarding this, how I can make the text to be wrapped on multiple lines?

Comment: Why do you want to write text on a `JPanel`? Did you consider using a text components like `JTextArea` or `JTextPane` for this?

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda i want to be transparend and I do also want to export the whole content of JPanel using a BufferedImage and Graphics.